# How to run a jbehave scenario is multiple browsers

Tags: jbehave

How to run jbehave scenario with multiple browers in parrell? I am passing browser name as run time parameter from bamboo and adding it to SauceWebDriverProvider in my code. I want to execute this scenario with multiple browsers parrell in sauce. Please help me in finding solution.Thanks

I have a scenario like this:

Scenario: +Login: User Logs into myapplication

Given I log into myappliation with  and valid password 
Then ensure that user is able to login myapplication

Examples:
|username|password|
|lee|password|